# Shared pointer lifetime

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

If I dereference a `shared_ptr` and invoke a method on the contained object, is the shared_ptr lifetime guaranteed?

Let's say:

```
stream.linkInfoPtr->addTxRxBytes( txBytes, rxBytes );
```

Where `linkInfoPtr` is `shared_ptr` and stored in the stream object. Does it mean if `linkInfoPtr` would be destroyed from another thread during `addTxRxBytes` invocation I would face a segfault?

Comment: As long as you have one shared pointer to the object (sharing the ownership of the object) the object will be kept alive. If you pass the shared pointer by value (and thereby sharing the ownership) to the threads, the object pointed to will not end its lifetime

Comment: yeah, but in this scope, I didn't have a copy of shared_ptr, that means I am potentially creating here a segfault possibility, right?

Comment: But isn't `linkInfoPtr` a copy of the shared pointer object? As long as you have this copy, and `linkInfoPtr` doesn't end its own life-time, the object it shares ownership of will be kept alive.

Comment: If another thread can destroy `linkInfoPtr` while this thread is accessing it, then your program contains a data race and therefore exhibits undefined behavior. The fact that `linkInfoPtr` happens to be of type `shared_ptr` isn't really relevant to this observation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that was my thought as well, in order to make it safe I have to obtain a copy of inkInfoPtr before calling addTxRxBytes, right?

auto linkPtr = stream.linkInfoPtr;
linkPtr->addTxRxBytes()

Comment: Please post real code not vague explanations.

Comment: It might be irrelevant. What happens if `linkInfoPtr` is destroyed from another thread *right before* this line?

Comment: If you have a data race, then obtaining a copy won't help. What if that other thread destroys `linkInfoPtr` just as you are about to copy it, right when `auto linkPtr = stream.linkInfoPtr` executes? You should concentrate on eliminating data races from your program, not on attempting to avoid their consequences - the latter is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If another thread destroys `linkInfoPtr`'s in a manner that is not synchronized with the line

```
stream.linkInfoPtr->addTxRxBytes( txBytes, rxBytes );
```

in this thread, then your program has a data race and therefore undefined behavior.

Only atomic variables may be accessed potentially in parallel for read and write without any additional synchronization, such as through a mutex or atomic operations.

It does not matter at all that `linkInfoPtr` is a `std::shared_ptr` or for what purpose it is written to and read from. This is true for all non-atomic types.

And even for an atomic type you would have undefined behavior, because one possible order of accesses would be that `linkInfoPtr` is destroyed before the other line is executed, in which case you have undefined behavior due to access out-of-lifetime.

---

Each thread needs its own copy of the `std::shared_ptr` and then you are guaranteed that the object the `std::shared_ptr` share ownership over and that you are calling `addTxRxBytes` on is alive until the calling thread destroys its instance of the `std::shared_ptr`.